# how to calculate the amount for total hours in javascript

Tags: javascript

i need to calculate the work in the hourly base, for one hour I spent `100` Rupee means, my total amount will `100` Like that i need to calculate the hours to amount in javascript. example code

```
var timeSpent = 1:25:58, //1:26
    amountPerhours = 100;
```

how to calculate the total amount based on working hours in javascript

Comment: and what did you already tried?

Comment: `(26/60)*100` ???

Comment: atleast show for an hour then ask for help

Answer (score 2):

You could get first the decimal representation of the time and multiply it then with the hour factor. Later you might add some fixing.

```js
var timeSpent = '1:25:58',
    amountPerHour = 100,
    time = timeSpent
        .split(':')
        .reduce((r, a, i) => r + a * Math.pow(60, -i), 0),
    result = time * amountPerHour;
    
console.log('time', time);
console.log('amount', result.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to split your input variables:

```
var hours = 3;
var minutes = 25;
var seconds = 58;
var amount = 100;

var result = hours*amount + minutes*amount/60 + seconds*amount/3600;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function getAmount(timeSpent) {
    var amountPerhour = 100;
    var time = timeSpent.split(":");
    var hours = time[0];
    var mins = time[1];
    var secs = time[2];

    if (secs != undefined && secs > 29) {
        mins++;
    }
    var amount = (+hours + +mins/60) * amountPerhour;
    return parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2);
}

console.log(getAmount("1:25:58"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The amount can easily be calculated in one line. Refer to the below snippet.

```js
var time = "1:25:30";
var amount = time.split(":")
    .map((a,b) => a/(60**b))
    .reduce((a,b) => a+b)
    .toFixed(2) * 100;
console.log(amount);
```